# how to add background just for text not for line in Tkinter python

Tags: python, tkinter

I  want to add background just for text not line . I  work with Tkinter an text_widget

```
  # text widget
        self.text_widget = Text(self.window, width=10, height=50, bg='white', fg=TEXT_COLOR,
        font=FONT, padx=20, pady=20, wrap=WORD,relief='raised')
        self.text_widget.place(relheight=0.745, relwidth=0.98, rely=0.08)
        self.text_widget.configure(cursor="arrow", state=DISABLED)
        msg2 = f"{bot_name}: {healthcare}\n\n"
        self.text_widget.configure(state=NORMAL)
        self.text_widget.tag_config(tagName="respHealth", background="#2ECC71", foreground="black")
       self.text_widget.insert(END, msg2, 'respHealth')
```

the problem I have
[capture of backround](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gFjcN.png)

Comment: Have you looked at `tkinter.Text` tags? You can add a tag on your text and configure the tag's foreground/background colour. Also please show us some minimal working code

Comment: yeah I do that  but the problem when I add background  .she take whole line  .not just text please see the picture I send  . I want make chat application

Comment: please show how You add background using Text tags, also `.place()` shouldn't really be used because `.pack()` or `.grid()` can do better unless for some reason You just have to have a widget at some specific coordinates which You don't in this case so it would be better to use either `.pack()` or `.grid()`

Comment: this code show how I use background 
```
  self.text_widget.tag_config(tagName="respHealth", background="#2ECC71", foreground="black")
```

Comment: great so the tag works as intended, I see no issue except You not providing enough code to figure out what the issue is

Comment: what is this code  please

Comment: that is the question I am asking you btw. how do you set those tags?

Comment: any tags ? please

Comment: see here You use: `self.text_widget.tag_config(tagName="respHealth", background="#2ECC71", foreground="black")` which is configuring a tag, the question is how do You create that tag? what are the indexes. just provide a [mre] that includes how this happens, it is that simple

Comment: ` self.text_widget.tag_config(tagName="respHealth", background="#2ECC71", foreground="black")`

Comment: how do You create that tag?

Comment: I edit the code in post.  please see the code

Comment: what happens if You remove both newlines from msg2? because it seems to me that it tags the whole text which means it includes those newlines which would explain marking the whole line

Comment: Yes you're right. thank you